# How is this called overloading - Java

Tags: java, binding, static, overloading

I have this class BindingSample with a method that takes no parameter

```
public class BindingSample {
  public void printMsg(){
      System.out.println("Binding Sample no parameter");
  }
}
```

---

**And another class that extends the BindingSample and uses the same method signature but adds a parameter to it**

```
public class application extends BindingSample {

  public void printMsg(int i){
        System.out.println("Changed my value " + i);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        application app = new application();
        app.printMsg(5);
  }
}
```

The output is Changed my value 5

Why did it work even if the parameters are different? And why is it called overloading? I don't think it's overriding because to override a method, the method signature and its parameter should be the same.

Comment: *same method signature but adds a parameter to it*... method overloading

Comment: Add `app.printMsg()` and you will see the super method.

Answer (score 1):

> Why did it work even if the parameters are different?

You `application` class has a `printMsg` method that takes a single `int` argument. Therefore `app.printMsg(5)` works.

Note that making the following change will cause your code not to pass compilation:

```
BindingSample app = new application();
app.printMsg(5);
```

since now the compiler can't find a `printMsg` method in the `BindingSample` class that takes an `int` argument.

> And why is it called overloading? I don't think it's overriding because to override a method, the method signature and its parameter should be the same

Overriding and overloading are two different concepts.

Method overloading occurs when multiple methods share the same name but have different number of arguments or different types of arguments.

Your `application` class has two `printMsg` methods (one inherited from its super class) with a different number of arguments. Hence this is method overloading.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading means just the names of the methods should be same. Everything else can be different (e.g. arguments, return types, throwable exceptions etc). As both the methods in the example have same name, it's called Overloading.

The reason why it works is, Overloading is compile time phenomena, compiler just checks for accessibility of the method to the object that's calling it. As you are instantiating `application` class and calling `printMsg` method with `int` argument. It works fine because of the method being present in the class (or being accessible to that object).